# Best way to design flows based on operations

Tags: design, python, object-oriented-design

This is the problem: I am designing a framework that is basically getting chemical compounds, perform operation with them (or among them) and return results.

At the moment I have a class that holds all the operations(like mix, centrifugate, separate, heat up and so on). I create a sequence basically by hand, including this class and adding the actions one after another. This is OK for me, since I am a developer, but many of my coworkers do work mostly in a lab environment, and they are not willing to get into writing a new file as such.

I am planning to shift to JSON, holding in there a sequence of operations; although I am not sure if this is the right way to create a series of operations, for the lab technicians. Is there a better design to accomplish something similar to my needs?

By "better" I mean something that is safe for the data, easy to use and maintain and performant. Term very generic, especially in the design context.

Comment: How do you define "better?"

Comment: Hmm, a bit vague; let me be more specific: Safer(data wise), easier to use for people not much into development, more efficient, easy to maintain. I understand that there is no such thing as better or worst, since they are tied to the context; but there are better practices and worst practices, that in the long run assure that you don't go insane working on your own code. Better is probably an incorrect term, I agree

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are writing the whole system or only adding a "configuration engine" over the top of an existing system. If you are only making a configuration engine for a stable system then advanced techniques may make sense. If you are writing the whole system then it's better to let the system mature before attempting to add a sophisticated capability to configure it such as a domain specific language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON (as well as XML) are formats made for transferring information in **machine readable** form. They can be managed by humans, of course, but for many use cases there are more ergonomic ways to accomplish what you are after. The modern buzzword for this is [Domain Specific Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), which means you might invent your own "mini-language" which suits your (and your coworkers) needs, and write a parser and interpreter for it.

If your use case just involves a sequence of operations with some parameters, this is very simple and should not be a big issue. Just define one command for each operation, and let your coworkers write the commands into a text file. In our company, we often used spreadsheet files in the past for such command sequences, which makes it a little bit more "user friendly", since in a spreadsheet you can add easily some things like comments, integrated examples, validations, separated parameter columns etc. If you need something more sophisticated, google for *"domain specific language python"*, and you will find plenty of articles, tutorials and modules.

Comment: I was not aware of Domain Specific Languages; indeed it make sense to go in that direction; I am going to explore over it. Thanks!